# Need help on Index out of bounds exception on arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So this is my code. when i run the test, it gives me the index out of bounds error and highlghts the if

```
(songList.get(j).getDuration()<(songList.get(j-1).getDuration())  )
        {
```

portion of the code. how do i fix this???
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
/**
 * Write a description of class SongList here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class SongList
{

  private ArrayList <Song> songList;
/**
     * Constructor for objects of class SongList
     */
    public SongList()
    {
     songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

}

public boolean addSong(Song s)

        {

         songList.add(s);

         return true;   
        }

    public int findSong(String title)
    {
      for  (int i=0; i < songList.size(); ++i)
       {
       if ( songList.get(i).getTitle().compareTo(title) == 0)
       return i;
    }
    return -1 ; 


}

public  void swapSong(int i, int j)
    {

        Song[  ] ai = new Song [100];
        Song temp = ai[i];
        ai[i] = ai[j];
        ai[j] = temp;    
    }


public void sortByDuration()
{
for(int i=0; i < songList.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; ++j)
    {
         if (songList.get(j).getDuration()<(songList.get(j-1).getDuration())  )
        {

            swapSong(j,j-1);

        }


    }   

}


}


public void sortByWriter()
{
 for(int i=0; i < songList.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; --j)
    {
  if( songList.get(j).getWriter().compareTo(songList.get(j-i).getWriter())<0)
  {


  swapSong(j,j-1);

}
}
}
}



public void sortByGenre()
{
    for(int i=0; i < songList.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; --j)
    {
  if (songList.get(j).getGenre().compareTo(songList.get(j-1).getGenre())<0)
  swapSong(j,j-1);
}
}}



public  void sortByYear()
{
    for(int i=0; i < songList.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; --j)
    {
if (songList.get(j).getYear()<(songList.get(j-1).getYear()))
swapSong(j,j-1);

}
}}


public int getSize()
{
    return songList.size();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to start at the end of your `ArrayList` with your `j` `for` loop.

```
for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; ++j)
```

However, this increases `j` so you run off the end of the `ArrayList`.

Decrease `j` instead, so you won't run off the end, and so the loop will eventually have `j` meet `i` and terminate:

```
//                                      HERE
for (int j = songList.size()-1; j > i ; --j)
```

Your other `j` `for` loops already do `--j` correctly.